# Grab id from upper left and lower right cells of a selection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently I have 1440 data points in a table row.  Multiple Rows.
The number of rows can vary, but the the time stamp remains the same no matter which row.

What i am looking to do is "zoom" in on the data by highlighting multiple cells and grabbing only the timestamp of the upper left and lower right corners to pass them to PHP to grab data only from that time frame.  So the action would be on mouse release.

For instance here is a snippet

```
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533704400"></td>
  <td bgcolor="red" id="1533704460"></td>
  <td bgcolor="orange" id="1533704520"></td>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533704580"></td>
  ...
  ...
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533772620"></td>
  <td bgcolor="yellow" id="1533772680"></td>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533772740"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="blue" id="1533704400"></td>
  <td bgcolor="yellow" id="1533704460"></td>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533704520"></td>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533704580"></td>
  ...
  ...
  <td bgcolor="purple" id="1533772620"></td>
  <td bgcolor="blue" id="1533772680"></td>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533772740"></td>
</tr>
...
...
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533704400"></td>
  <td bgcolor="red" id="1533704460"></td>
  <td bgcolor="orange" id="1533704520"></td>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533704580"></td>
  ...
  ...
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533772620"></td>
  <td bgcolor="yellow" id="1533772680"></td>
  <td bgcolor="green" id="1533772740"></td>
</tr>
```

The output looks like this:

[image: The "graph" as it appears with all datapoints]

So if you make a mouse selection, you will get 2 values, say 1533729660 and  1533740340, then I can pass those to PHP when you unclick to generate a "zoomed in" version with that number of data points.

My first question, is is this even possible? I have been scowering the web for a few days and cannot find anything related to this.  I am looking to do the same things that graphs do but there is no graph type for this output

My Second question is, I don't think I can use ID, as ID is supposed to be unique, in my case there will be duplicates per roll.

Comment: You're correct about ID being unique. If you have multiple elements that will use the same ID try using something like `data-id="1533704400"`. As far as 'zooming in' you could think of it like how when you do a search on Google you only see 10 results out of thousands. You will need to be able to show just a portion of the total. Use your PHP to restrict the amount of data and display just that.

Comment: @Ricca The thing is the graph shows one day of activity (1440 minutes).  This is by design.  However it has been requested that we have a zoom feature added so they can zoom in on a particular time frame.  The Data-id is already used as when you click a cell, the info about the event pops up, so it cannot be used.  As for restricting the data, that is the plan, once the time values for start and end are given by the mouse selection.